# is there any difference between the key and object_key in a S3.Object() in boto3?

Tags: boto3

The documentation for [S3.Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/object/index.html) and [S3.ObjectVersion](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/objectversion/index.html#objectversion) mention `key`(identifier) and `object_key` (attribute). But I don't see any difference:

```
import boto3

all_objects = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('mybucket').object_versions.all()
for obj in all_objects:
  print(obj.key, obj.object_key)
  print(obj.id, obj.version_id)
```

When should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safe option when reading it is to use `key` because all [ObjectSummary](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/objectsummary/index.html), [Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/object/index.html) and [ObjectVersion](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/objectversion/index.html) have `key` but [ObjectSummary](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/objectsummary/index.html) does not have `object_key`.

So if you want to use consistent syntax without having to worry about the exact type returned by the boto3 method, you can use `.key` and it will work for both `mybucket.object_versions.all()` and `mybucket.objects.all()` because both have `.key`